# Define datasource parameters to get value from a label? ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, datasource

I'm writing a function (by datasource) that i called 'similar products', showing in ProductDetails page.

It's grab the ProductID from url by QueryString, and i want it to get the Price value also, for calculating the same price for similar products, the Price value is in ProductDetails page and it's a label.

I can config the datasource for grab the ProductID, but dont know how to get the label's value.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but if you want to set the parameters of an object data source in code, you can create a ControlParameter:

`ObjectDataSource o = new ObjectDataSource("<type>", "<select method>");
ControlParameter cp = new ControlParameter();
cp.ControlID = "<Label ID>";
o.SelectParameters.Add(cp);`

Comment: How you grab the ProductId from url ? Do you send Ajax request to show similar products ?